# How do you put integers onto the end of a list so that it does not become an "Attribute Error" in Python?

Tags: python, list, extend

I am making an average calculator, which calculates the mean average of numbers that are chosen by the user. Here is my code so far:

```
p = 1

print("How many numbers would you like the calculate the average of?")
k = int(input())

NUMBERS = ("m")

for x in range(k):
    u = (x + 1)
     print("What is Number ",u,"?",sep="")
    num = int(input())
    NUMBERS.extend("",num,"")
print(NUMBERS(2))
```

Expected Result:

```
How many numbers would you like the calculate the average of?  
>>>2
What is Number 1?
>>>5
What is Number 2?
>>>8
2
```

So far, I am trying to see whether it is put onto the end of the list, but it ends up as an `Attribute Error`.

Actual Result:

```
How many numbers would you like the calculate the average of?
>>>2
What is Number 1? 
>>>5
```

> "Line 12, in   NUMBERS.extend("",num,"")  AttributeError:
>   "str" object has no attribute "extend".

Comment: Lists use `[]`, not `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have attribute errors like this, make sure the object has the correct type.  The error says it's a string, not a list.  That's important information.

```
In [132]: n = ("m")                                                             
In [133]: n                                                                     
Out[133]: 'm'
```

`()` just group things; by themselves they don't create a list (or tuple)

```
In [134]: n = ("m",)                                                            
In [135]: n                                                                     
Out[135]: ('m',)
```

Inclusion of a `,` creates a tuple.  But a tuple does not have an `extend` method either.

You want a list:

```
In [136]: n = ["m"]                                                             
In [137]: n                                                                     
Out[137]: ['m']
In [138]: n.extend(1,2,3)                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-138-7b03428a3fa3> in <module>
----> 1 n.extend(1,2,3)

TypeError: extend() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
```

and you want to give `extend` a list, not multiple arguments:

```
In [139]: n.extend(["one","two","three"])                                       
In [140]: n                                                                     
Out[140]: ['m', 'one', 'two', 'three']
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should define your list with `[]` instead of `()` -> `NUMBERS = ["m"]`

Then, the `append()` function adds an element at the end of the list.

So, here is your code with these two modifications :

```py
p = 1

print("How many numbers would you like the calculate the average of?")
k = int(input())

NUMBERS = ["m"]

for x in range(k):
    u = (x + 1)
     print("What is Number ",u,"?",sep="")
    num = int(input())
    NUMBERS.append(num)
print(NUMBERS(2))
```

**Note:** I'm not sure to understand why you initialize your list with a `"m"` nor why you add empty strings `""` in it but this answer your question. If you give more details about the rest of the script, I would be happy to help.